# MongoDB: How do I update a single subelement in an array, referenced by the index within the array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to update a single subelement contained within an array in a mongodb document. I want to reference the field using its array index (elements within the array don't have any fields that I can guarantee will be unique identifiers). Seems like this should be easy to do, but I can't figure out the syntax.

Here's what I want to do in pseudo-json.

Before:

```
{
  _id : ...,
  other_stuff ... ,
  my_array : [
    { ... old content A ... },
    { ... old content B ... },
    { ... old content C ... }
  ]
}
```

After:

```
{
  _id : ...,
  other_stuff ... ,
  my_array : [
    { ... old content A ... },
    { ... NEW content B ... },
    { ... old content C ... }
  ]
}
```

Seems like the query should be something like this:

```
//pseudocode
db.my_collection.update(
  {_id: ObjectId(document_id), my_array.1 : 1 },
  {my_array.$.content: NEW content B }
)
```

But this doesn't work. I've spent way too long searching the mongodb docs, and trying different variations on this syntax (e.g. using `$slice`, etc.). I can't find any clear explanation of how to accomplish this kind of update in MongoDB.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

As expected, the query is easy once you know how.  Here's the syntax, in python:

```
db["my_collection"].update(
    { "_id": ObjectId(document_id) },
    { "$set": { 'documents.'+str(doc_index)+'.content' : new_content_B}}
)
```

Comment: where is this documented?

Comment: This ends up creating an object of the same name instead of updating the array

Comment: That is definitly an obsolete answer.

Comment: This answer is obsolete.  Rather than adding confusion, this question is asking about how to modify an element of an array *where that element is an object* hence, see the docs here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/?_ga=1.12567092.1864968360.1429722620#update-documents-in-an-array

Answer (score 74):

Update of an array element referenced by an index (e.g. 1 ) in Mongo Shell can also be done by directly indicating the index value:

```
db.my_collection.update(
    {_id : "document_id"},
    {$set : {"my_array.1.content" : "New content B"}}
)
```

Comment: How do we do it if we don't know the index ?

Answer (score 69):

In mongo style, using '$' positional operator.
Check out this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/?_ga=1.12567092.1864968360.1429722620#up._S_) for details.

```
db.my_collection.update(
  {_id: ObjectId(document_id), my_array.1 : 1 },
  { $set: { "my_array.$.content" : "NEW content B" } }
)
```

Answer (score 61):

When it's required to update an array element without knowing it's actual index but having a **unique identifier of the element:**

```
// Modify a comment in a bucket
db.POST_COMMENT.update(
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ec424a1ed1af85a50855964"),
        "bucket.commentId": "5eaf258bb80a1f03cd97a3ad_lepf4f"
    },
    {
        $set: {
            "bucket.$.text": "Comment text changed",
            "bucket.$.createdDate": ISODate("2015-12-11T14:12:00.000+0000")
        }
    }
)
```

Here `"bucket.commentId"` is the unique identifier of an array element.

Comment: In Mongo shell with findAndModify, double quotes in `$set` does not work for me. I have to use single quotes for the field.

Comment: Where is the index ```$``` set?

Answer (score 18):

A neat way to do it in Javascript, with backticks, is:

```
 const index = 1;

 ...  {   $set: { [`myArray.${index}.value`]: "new content"}  },  ...
```

Comment: This is great because in a simliar way you can define the value field (or even the array) dynamically.

Comment: This is the correct way of defining dynamically.

Answer (score 10):

```
db.my_collection.update(
  {_id: ObjectId(document_id), my_array : { ... old content A ... } },
  { $set: { "my_array.$.content" : "NEW content B" } }
)
```

Answer (score 10):

*When it's required to update an array element without knowing it's an actual index but having a unique identifier of the element*

```
db.getCollection('profiles').update(
  {
    'userId':'4360a380-1540-45d9-b902-200f2d346263',
    'skills.name':'css'
  },
  {
      $set: {'skills.$.proficiencyLevel': 5}
  }, 
  {
      multi: true
  }
)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to update the authorName of the testimonial having _id = 60c4918d74c30165ba585c14 from the following document:

```
"business": {
    "ownerId": "60a5ebad7432d91b853c0277",
    "testimonials": [
        {
            "_id": "60c4912877dd5664f2201b08",
            "authorName": "user1",
            "authorBio": "User from 10 years",
            "image": "user1/img1",
            "review": "asdfiuahsdfpoiuashdpfoaspdlfkjn;alsfpuoh"
        },
        {
            "_id": "60c4918d74c30165ba585c14",
            "authorName": "user2",
            "authorBio": "User from 3 years",
            "image": "user/img1",
            "review": "asdpfuahsfljnsadfoihsf."
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-06-11T20:12:56.666Z",
    "updatedAt": "2021-06-12T11:11:56.696Z",
    
}
```

Then the following mongoose query works:

```
await BusinessModel.updateOne(
        {
            '_id': Mongoose.Types.ObjectId(businessId),
            'testimonials._id': Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('60c4918d74c30165ba585c14')
        },
        {
            $set: { 'testimonials.$.authorName' : 'new author name' } 
        }
    );
```

Also refer to https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/crud/write-operations/embedded-arrays/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the updateOne function of mongoDB passing the index of the element in array, if the key of *old content B* is "value" per example:

```
[
...
"value" : "old content A"
"value" : "old content B"
"value" : "old content C"
...
]
```

the command should be like this:

```
db.collection.updateOne({"_id" : "...,"},{$set: {"my_array.1.value": "NEW content B"}})
```

Comment: How do we do it if we don't know the index ?

Comment: You can refer to my answer -- you can match the id of the item you want to update.

Answer (score 0):

I needed an `updateMany` (not `updateOne` as shown in accepted answer), and I think it's [important to call out the `arrayFilters` argument.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#mongodb-method-db.collection.updateMany)

The `arrayFilters` argument is:

> Optional. An array of filter documents that determine **which array elements to modify for an update operation on an array field**.

Here's the example from MongoDb documentation:

> ### Update Elements Match `arrayFilters` Criteria
>
> Create a collection students with the following documents:
>
> ```
> db.students.insertMany( [
>    { "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 95, 92, 90 ] },
>    { "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 98, 100, 102 ] },
>    { "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 95, 110, 100 ] }
> ])
> ```
>
> To update all elements that are greater than or equal to 100 in the grades array, use the filtered positional operator $[] with the arrayFilters option:
>
> ```
> db.students.updateMany(
>    { grades: { $gte: 100 } },
>    { $set: { "grades.$[element]" : 100 } },
>    { arrayFilters: [ { "element": { $gte: 100 } } ] }
> )
> ```
>
> After the operation, the collection contains the following documents:
>
> ```
> { "_id" : 1, "grades" : [ 95, 92, 90 ] }
> { "_id" : 2, "grades" : [ 98, 100, 100 ] }
> { "_id" : 3, "grades" : [ 95, 100, 100 ] }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a "plain" array containing simple strings, this did the trick:

```
db.paintings.insertMany([
  {_id: 1, colors: ["red", "blue", "green"]},
  {_id: 2, colors: ["red", "yellow"]}

db.paintings.updateMany(
  {colors: "red"},
  {$set: {"colors.$": "magenta"}})
```

> the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document
> [Source](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#mongodb-update-up.-)