# Updating value for list array field in mongoDB with python

Tags: python, mongodb, list, dictionary

I have the following docs:

```js
{
  "_id": "xyz",
  "data": {
    "cat": {
      
    },
    "exec": [
      {
        "orderNo": "2345",
        "status": "pending"
      },
      {
        "orderNo": "8907",
        "status": "Approved"
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "_id": "abc",
  "data": {
    "cat": {
      
    },
    "exec": [
      {
        "orderNo": "0098",
        "status": "pending"
      },
      {
        "orderNo": "3456",
        "status": "pending"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I intend to do is write a query which would effectively identify the order based on `"_id"` and `"orderNo"` and update the `"status"` to 'Approved'.

Comment: What you have tried so far, please post that as part of the question

Comment: Look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) which has some tips on how to ask a great question that'll get you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How do I update a single subelement in an array, referenced by the index within the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372065/mongodb-how-do-i-update-a-single-subelement-in-an-array-referenced-by-the-inde)