# How to update field from embedded document from an array in pymongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo for programming.
I want to update a field from an embedded document from an array which is stored in the MongoDB database. I can update it directly from the mongo shell by using the dot `(.)` operator like

Ex:

```
db.coll.update({},{"year.0.month":5})
```

But if I use the same `year.0.month` in pymongo, I am unable to update it as it giving me an error.

Can someone please elaborate how can I achieve this in pymongo?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$set` to update. e.g

```
db.coll.update({},{ "$set": {"year.0.month":5}}))
```

By the way from version 3 `update()` is depricated, So for update single document use `update_one` or `find_one_and_update()` e.g

```
db.coll.update_one({},{ "$set": {"year.0.month":5}})
```

or

```
db.coll.update_one_and_update({},{ "$set": {"year.0.month":5}})
```

And for update many doc use `update_many()` e.g

```
db.coll.update_many({},{ "$set": {"year.0.month":5}},multi=True)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. the issue is, pymongo is not accepting "year.0.month" format. Do yo know its equivalent syntax for pymongo?

Comment: could you please show me your sample doc @RupashriPatil

Comment: But above one should work did you get any error then show me or you can check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372065/mongodb-how-do-i-update-a-single-subelement-in-an-array-referenced-by-the-inde)

Comment: This is the similar one which i am trying. Error is: WriteError(u'cannot use the part (comments of comments.comment_ordinal.num_likes) to traverse the element ({comments: [ { author: "Tonia Surace", body: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, ...", email: "DcwPJgyw@mCBzxAfy.com", num_likes: 1 }])

Comment: Try to use positional operator `$` the. Do you want to push a new element into the array? then you should use `$push`.

Comment: you are making mistake elsewhere