# How to insert data in array of 0 object in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my structure of mongodb. I need to add field in 0 object of array.
Can some one please help

```
_id:ObjectId("5c2cdb3cdd03242b5c15965a")
    Article:Array
    0:Object
    name:"dublin"
```

I tried this but it is not working.

```
 db.myCollection.update({_id:ObjectId("5c2cdb3cdd03242b5c15965a")},{$set:{Article:[{regarding:"nodeDeveloper"}]}})
```

I need output like this

```
_id:ObjectId("5c2cdb3cdd03242b5c15965a")
Article:Array
0:Object
name:"dublin"
regarding:"nodeDeveloper"
```

Comment: The way you describe MongoDB objects is very confusing.

Comment: Yuor answer is here...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372065/mongodb-how-do-i-update-a-single-subelement-in-an-array-referenced-by-the-inde