# Find and update of object in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this mongoose schema

```
{
    id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    name: String,
    initialMailSended: Boolean,
    email: String,
    users: [{
        id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        name: String,
        surname: String,
        email: String,
        signedUp: Boolean,
        company: String,
        email: String,
        attending: String,
        accomod: String,
        program: String,
        food: String,
        other: String,
        allFood: String,
        form: [{
            name: String,
            value: String,
        }]
    }]
}
```

What i need to do is write a mongoose query which find this object by id and in this object find user and update it. 
I tried various queries but didn't find any which would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: How do I update a single subelement in an array, referenced by the index within the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372065/mongodb-how-do-i-update-a-single-subelement-in-an-array-referenced-by-the-inde)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, you can update your user like this

```
db.getCollection('collection').findOneAndUpdate(
    {
      _id:ObjectId("5cb19dbc85fdcb7868400107"),       // collection id
     'users._id':ObjectId("5cb19dbc85fdcb7868400185") // user id inside collection
    },

    {$set: {'users.$.name': 'new value'}}            // set name field
)
```

also see this question [Updating a Nested Array with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577123/updating-a-nested-array-with-mongodb)

Comment: `Actions.find({
            _id: actionId,
            'users._id': userId

        }, (err, data) => {
            //console.log(data[0].users);
            console.log('data', data);
        })`

this solution return data with all objects in array

Comment: SOLVED - The problem was using fixed value instead of $ in $set part of solution