# Mongoose: How to update sub embedded document array?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Here is my Schema

```
const NetworkSchema = new Schema({
 user: {
 type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
 ref: 'user'
},
name: {
  type: String
},
friendrequests: [
{
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  status: {
    type: String,
    default: 'pending'
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
}
],

});
```

I want to update my sub embedded document friendrequest using it's _id. I'm still new to mongoose please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay managed to update sub embedded document using updateOne

```
  const network = await Network.updateOne(
   {
     user: req.user.id,
     'friendrequests._id': req.params.friendrequest_id
   },
   {
     $set: { 'friendrequests.$.status': 'accepted' }
   }
  );
```

Referrence: [MongoDB: How do I update a single subelement in an array, referenced by the index within the array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11372065/mongodb-how-do-i-update-a-single-subelement-in-an-array-referenced-by-the-inde)