# Update array at specific index by other filed in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, pipeline

I have a collection, consist of `name` and `data`.

`data` is an array with 2 elements, each element is the object with `code` and `qty`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd2"),
    "name" : "Anna",
    "data" : [
        {
            "code" : "a",
            "qty" : 3
        },
        {
            "code" : "b",
            "qty" : 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd3"),
    "name" : "James",
    "data" : [
        {
            "code" : "c",
            "qty" : 5
        },
        {
            "code" : "d",
            "qty" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to update the `code` of the first element to `name` of its document. The result I want is

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd2"),
    "name" : "Anna",
    "data" : [
        {
            "code" : "Anna",
            "qty" : 3
        },
        {
            "code" : "b",
            "qty" : 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd3"),
    "name" : "James",
    "data" : [
        {
            "code" : "James",
            "qty" : 5
        },
        {
            "code" : "d",
            "qty" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I just google to find how to:

1. **update array at a specific index** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34177929/11738185)

```
db.Collection.updateMany(
    { },
    {
        $set:{
            'data.0.code': '$name'
        }
    }
)
```

But the code of the first element in `data` array is a string '$name', not a value (Anna, James)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd2"),
    "name" : "Anna",
    "data" : [
        {
            "code" : "$name",
            "qty" : 3
        },
        {
            "code" : "b",
            "qty" : 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd3"),
    "name" : "James",
    "data" : [
        {
            "code" : "$name",
            "qty" : 5
        },
        {
            "code" : "d",
            "qty" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

2. **update a field by the value of another field**. It takes me to use pipeline updating (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37280419/11738185): the second param of `updateMany` is array (pipeline)

```
db.Collection.updateMany(
    { },
    [{
        $set:{
            'data.0.code': '$name'
        }
    }]
)
```

and It adds field `0` to each element in `data` array

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd2"),
    "name" : "Anna",
    "data" : [
        {
            "0" : {
                "code" : "Anna"
            },
            "code" : "a",
            "qty" : 3
        },
        {
            "0" : {
                "code" : "Anna"
            },
            "code" : "b",
            "qty" : 4
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("605c666a15d2612ed0afedd3"),
    "name" : "James",
    "data" : [
        {
            "0" : {
                "code" : "James"
            },
            "code" : "c",
            "qty" : 5
        },
        {
            "0" : {
                "code" : "James"
            },
            "code" : "d",
            "qty" : 6
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find the solution for this case. Could anyone to help me? How can I update array at fixed index by other field. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *1. **update array at a specific index***

You can't use internal fields as value of another fields, it will work only when you have external value to update like `{ $set: { "data.0.code": "Anna" } }`.

> *2. **update a field by the value of another field***

Update with Aggregation pipeline can't allow to access `data.0.code` syntax.

---

You can try using `$reduce` in update with aggregation pipeline,

- `$reduce` to iterate loop of `data` array, set empty array in initialValue of reduce, Check condition if initialValue array size is zero then replace `code` with `name` and merge with current object using `$mergeObjects`, else return current object,
- `$concatArrays` to concat current object with initialValue array

```
db.collection.update({},
  [{
    $set: {
      data: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$data",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                {
                  $cond: [
                    { $eq: [{ $size: "$$value" }, 0] },
                    { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { code: "$name" }] },
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-mqYJLUHNk_)